# Understand closure and limit points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I study Rudin's book on analysis. I want to check with you that I understand the definition of closure. Therefore I must check with you that I understand the definition of limit points.

1. A neighborhood is for example an interval, a circle or a sphere around a point or a set.
2. A limit point is any point that "can be approached as a limit" in contrast to an isolated point for example the set $\{\{1\}, [2,3]\}$ i.e. the union of the point $1$ and the interval between $2$ and $3$ has an isolated point $1$ which is not a limit point but any points between $2$ and $3$ are limit points.

Do you agree?

What I don't understand about closure is: How can there be limit points of a set $E$ which are outside of $E$? I think that the example is an open set but I don't get the picture. I think that the closure by definition always is a closed set and therefore the union of an open set and its limit points is not closed, but I still don't understand how a set can have a limit point not in the set.

I must have misunderstood.

Comment: You mean $\{1\}\cup[2,3]$, this is not the same as $\{\{1\}, [2,3]\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the set $ (0, 1) \subseteq \mathbb R $. Then $ 1 $ is a limit point of this set, but is not an element.

EDIT: A set with its limit points is always closed. One can show that $ \overline{A} = A \cup A' $ where $ A' $ is the set of limit points of $ A $, and the closure of a set is always closed.

Comment: I see. So a set can "have" a point which is not a member of the set?

Comment: You can have limit points not in the set. In fact, if you see my edit, you'll see that a set is closed precisely when it contains all of its limit points.

Comment: Thank you for the extended answer. Now I think that it follows that there is no closure of any open set. Do you agree?

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no closure"? For any set $ A $ we can define its closure to be the intersection of all closed sets containing it. This always exists, as we havs defined it explicitly.

Comment: I thought that the closure was the set plus its limit points. And that an open set plus any other set will result in an open set.

Comment: The definition I gave about the intersections and the one you gave about limit points are actually equivalent. And your statenent about open sets is false. $ (0, 1) $ is open, and if I add the point $ 0 $ I don't get an open set.

Comment: Excellent, now I understand. I had misunderstood the concept of union :-)

Comment: "For any set A we can define its closure to be the intersection of all closed sets containing it. "  You can, but Rudin doesn't.  Rudin defines the closure as the union of a set and it's limit points.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an important point that some of the other answers aren't putting clearly, and I think it's worth stating explicitly.

The phrase "the limit points of the set $A$" *doesn't make sense* on its own. People will *say* it, but it's shorthand for something more precise: as it stands, this phrase is missing a crucial piece of information. A correct way of putting this might be "the limit points of the *subset* $A$ of the topological space $X$", or "the limit points of the set $A$ *as a subspace of* $X$", or similar.

Limit points are always relative to an ambient space. For example, you can ask the question "what are the limit points of the set $(0,1)$ inside the space $X$?" for each of the following four spaces $X$, and you'll get four different answers:

1. $X = (0,1)$
2. $X = \mathbb{R}_{>0}$
3. $X = \mathbb{R}$ (with the usual topology)
4. $X = \mathbb{R}$, but now with the Zariski topology

Comment: Now I understand more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

> A neighborhood is for example an interval, a circle or a sphere around a point or a set.

Intuitively you have the right idea but you really must become more comfortable with a much more abstract concept.

An neighborhood is a collection of points within a certain distance of a point.  The reason circles and spheres are so commonly used is that using the the Euclidean metric for distance, is because  all points within a give distance make the shape of a circle (or sphere, or interval).  But if we used a different method of distance we'd get different sets. For example if we used the "taxi cab" metric where distance is not measured by a straight line but by adding the vertical offset to the horizontal offset and neighborhood (all the points where the vertical offset plus the horizontal offset or within a certain value) would not be a circle; it would be a diamond.  We can even have a "distance" where every two different points are *always* $1$ distance apart.  Thus a neighborhood could be either just the point itself (that's the only point within $\frac 12$) or every single point in the universe (that's all the points withing $2$).

> A limit point is any point that "can be approached as a limit" in contrast to an isolated point for example the set {{1}, [2,3]} i.e. the union of the point 1 and the interval between 2 and 3 has an isolated point 1 which is not a limit point but any points between 2 and 3 are limit points.

Yes, you are missing the point here.  Points in and of themselves are not limit points.  The point $1$ isn't a limit point by itself. It must be (or not be) a limit point *of a set*.  $1$ is a limit point of $(0,1)$; it is a limit point of $[-3,7]$.  It is a limit point of $\mathbb Q$.  It is a limit point of the irrational numbers.   It is *not* a limit point of $\mathbb Z$. It is *not* a limit point of $(2,3)$.  It is a limit point of $\{ 1-\frac 1n| n\in \mathbb N\}$.

If you want to think intuitively of what a limit point is, a limit point of a set $E$ is a point, $x$, so that there always points of $E$ that are "close" to $x$.

$1$ is a limit point of $(0,1)$.  Even though $1 \not \in (0,1)$ we can always find points in $(0,1)$ that are close to $1$.  If we want to find a number that is within hundred-billionth ($0.00000000001$) of $1$ we'd pick $0.9999999999$.  If we need something within $\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ were as tiny as we wanted it, we'd pick... some $x$ so that $1-\epsilon < x < 1$.

$1$ is a limit point of $[-3,7]$ for pretty much the same reason.  $1$ is smack dab in the middle of $[-3,7]$ and we can find $x\in [-3,7]$ as close as we want.

It is a limit point of $\mathbb Q$.  For any $\epsilon > 0$ we can find rational numbers $q$ so that $1-\epsilon < q < 1 + \epsilon$.

It is a limit point of the *ir*rationals, as well.  For any $\epsilon > 0$ we can find *ir*rational numbers $z$ so that $1-\epsilon < z < 1+\epsilon$.

$1$ is *not* a limit point of $\mathbb Z$. We can not find *ANY* integers (other than $1$ itself) within $\frac 14$ of $1$.  Take the neighborhood of *all* real numbers within $\frac 14$ of $1$ and there are not *any* integers at all (other than $1$.)

$1$ is not a limit point of $(2,3)$.  We can not find any elements of $(2,3)$ withing $\frac 14$ of $1$.

Notice: $1$ does not have to be in the set $E$ to be a limit point nor does being in the set guarantee that it is a limit point (it won't be if there aren't any *other* points nearby.)

> I think that the example is an open set but I don't get the picture.

$1$ is a limit point of $(0,1)$ because for every neighborhood $(1-\epsilon, 1 + \epsilon)$ there will always be points, $y$ so that $y\in (0,1)$ and $y\in (1-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon)$.

> I think that the closure by defintion always is a closed set .

That is true but not by definition.  Rudin proves it in Th. 2.27 a)

> therefore the union of an open set and its limit points is not closed,

Oh, but it is!.

Example $(0,1)$ is an open set.  $0$ and $1$ are limit points of $(0,1)$.  Also $(0,1)$ are *also* limit point.  But other than that there are not any other limit points.

So $(0,1)'=$ the set of limit points of $(0,1)$ is $[0,1]$

So $(0,1)\cup (0,1)' = (0,1) \cup [0,1] = [0,1]$.

And $[0,1]$ is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, it really depends on the [topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology) in question.

For example, given *any* set $X,$ the power set of $X$ is a topology on $X,$ and given **any** subset $A$ of $X,$ we have that $A$ is a neighborhood of all of its elements.

As for your second question, I will say that your understanding of "[limit point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point)" makes sense in many cases (metric spaces, for example), but doesn't hold universally. Let $X=\{1\}\cup[2,3],$ as in your example, and define a topology $\mathcal T$ on $X$ by $$\mathcal T=\{\emptyset\}\cup\{A\subseteq X:1\in A\}.$$ Then it turns out that $1$ is the ***only*** limit point in $X$! For any other point $x$ of $X,$ the set $X\setminus\{x\}$ is closed. However, $X\setminus\{1\}$ is *not* closed. Thus, $1$ is a limit point in $X.$ In fact, it is a limit point of *every* non-empty subset of $X,$ except for $\{1\}.$

> Let $A\subseteq X$ such that $A\neq\{1\}$ and $A\neq\emptyset.$ Then there is some $r\in A$ such that $r\neq 1.$ Now, take any neighborhood $U$ of $r.$ Since $U\neq\emptyset,$ then by definition of $\mathcal T,$ we have that $1\in U.$ Since $r\neq 1$ and since $U$ was an arbitrary neighborhood of $r\in A,$ then $1$ is a limit point of $A.$ $\Box$

Comment: I think this answer might be a little bit overly complicated for this question. Not that it's wrong or bad, it's great but the OP is discussing limit points as defined in Rudin's mathematical analysis which discusses only metric spaces. Abstract topological spaces are not discussed in Rudin's mathematical analysis at all.

Comment: @stressedout: Fair enough. That said, nothing in the OP gave any definitions. I'm left to either visit my storage unit to dig out my copy of Rudin, or to answer as best I can to the question as asked.

Comment: Sure. As I said, your answer is fine and great.

Comment: Appreciated! I provided the Wikipedia links, just in case the poster hadn't heard of "topology" or "limit points" in general, so perhaps my answer will be edifying, nonetheless.

Comment: " That said, nothing in the OP gave any definitions. I'm left to either visit my storage unit to dig out my copy of Rudin, or to answer as best I can to the question as asked. "  What?  You don't sleep with your Rudin on your nightstand next to you?!  I thought *everybody* did!  ... (I do, but I also have a *lot* of other things on my nightstand....)

Answer (score 1):

The closure of a set is indeed closed because it contains all its limit points. That directly follows from the definition of being closed in metric spaces. At least the way Rudin defines it.

However, for showing you an example where the limit point of a set might not be an element of it, consider $(0,1]$. $0$ is a limit point because $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ is a sequence that approaches $0$ but it's not in the set.

Answer (score 1):

The term "neighborhood" to many authors ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)), for instance) is often broader than just an open/closed ball, and this actually confused me for a while in my topology course$^\dagger$.  If we have a metric space $X$ and a point $x \in X$, then a neighborhood $A$ of $x$ is any subset $A \subset X$ such that there exists an open ball of some radius $\delta >0$ that is contained entirely inside of $A$.

If we take $X$ to be instead a general topological space, then $A$ is a neighborhood of $x$ whenever there is an open set $Y \subset A$ that contains $x$.

In particular, a neighborhood doesn't *need* to be open nor does it need to be closed nor does it need to be connected (even inside a connected space).  This loose definition allows for things like $(0,1) \cup (2,3]$ to be a neighborhood of $2.5 \in \mathbb{R}$ despite containing lots of "irrelevant" points.  To make things more precise, you'll often see authors opt for the term *open neighborhood* of $x$, in which case what's being referred to is an open set containing $x$, but this still allows for things like $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$ to be a neighborhood of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \in \mathbb{R}$.

---

**Forewarning Footnote**:

Point-set topology (which, in a sense, generalizes much of the first couple chapters of Rudin) is notorious for sometimes having terms whose definitions vary slightly from author to author, so it's important to check how your particular author has defined their terms.  An example that immediately springs to mind is "locally compact": when the space isn't [Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space), there are a handful of inconsistent definitions that you can read about [**here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space#Formal_definition).

More examples arise due to the prefix "quasi-" (you can thank [Bourbaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki) for this, IIRC).  Whereas many people use "compact" to describe *any* space in which an open cover admits a finite subcover, others take it to mean this definition *plus* Hausdorff.  To such people, a space that fulfills the covering condition but is not necessarily Hausdorff is instead called *quasi-compact*.  Likewise, you'll sometimes encounter terms like *quasi-regular*, *quasi-normal*, and so forth—all referring to regular / normal / what-have-you spaces that are not necessarily Hausdorff.

---

$^\dagger$For example, one sometimes encounters the term "compact neighborhood" ([**here**](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Neighborhood_in_Compact_Hausdorff_Space_Contains_Compact_Neighborhood), e.g.).  While "neighborhood of a point" is interchangeable with "an open set containing that point" in most contexts, a compact set in a Hausdorff space is necessarily closed and not necessarily open!  For instance, there are no compact open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$.